# Numbering equations including enumerate environment in the label

Tags: equations, numbering, enumerate

I would like number equations including `enumerate` environment; I mean

I want something like

section.subsection.enumerate.equation

Could it be possible?

I was using that code

```
\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
\counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}
\counterwithin*{equation}{enumi}
\renewcommand\theequation{\ifnum\value{enumi}>0 \theenumi\else
                          \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \thesubsection\else
                          \thesection\fi\fi.\arabic{equation}}
```

But it doesn't work as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the condition to check whether you're inside an `enumerate` environment by setting a switch as soon as you enter `\begin{enumerate}` (thanks to [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}`). This switch is then used to condition on adding `\theenumi` to `\theequation`. The other conditionals check whether you're within a `\section` or `\subsection`, adding the counter representations accordingly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr,etoolbox}

\newif\ifinenumerate
\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\inenumeratetrue}

\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
\counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}
\counterwithin*{equation}{enumi}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\theequation{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \thesubsection.\else
  \ifnum\value{section}>0 \thesection.\fi\fi
  \ifinenumerate \theenumi.\fi
  \arabic{equation}}
\makeatother

% Just to show the equation number formatting
\newcommand{\printeqnum}[1]{%
  \setcounter{equation}{\numexpr#1-1}%
  \begin{equation}
    f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
  \end{equation}}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\printeqnum{4}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \printeqnum{7}
  \item \printeqnum{9}
\end{enumerate}


\subsection{A subsection}

\printeqnum{12}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \printeqnum{15}
  \item \printeqnum{18}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```